# Check mode uiimage selected from gallery with swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

When I select an image from gallery there are "mode1" like this (where the image is in landscape) [image: image1]  and "mode2" like this (where the image is in portrait) [image: image2]

the image have to be in mode scaleAspectFit, I want to show a button to change the content mode only for uiimages mode1.

for that I want to check if the selected image is mode1 or mode2.
How can I do that?

this is my code:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.delegate = self
picker.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

if let original = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage{
    pickerImg_seleccionada = original
}
if let img_seleccionada = pickerImg_seleccionada {
    imageuser.image = img_seleccionada
    //here I want to check if image is like mode1 the button should appear
}
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to check the orientation of image?

Comment: yes @TheTiger but I don't know how to do that

Comment: `img_seleccionada.imageOrientation == .up` for portrait?

Comment: I will try to do that

Comment: No @TheTiger does not work only I want to know if the image is in full screen like mode2 or center like mode1

Comment: It means you don't need to check orientation. In your case if `image.size.width >= image.size.height` it will be mode1.

Comment: @TheTiger that is correct my friend thanks :D :D, I want to check your answer as correct, please answer my question :D

Comment: BTW! You can vote up too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case if `imageWidth >= imageHeight` then it will be centered on screen so that `mode1`.

```
if img_seleccionada.size.width >= img_seleccionada.size.height {
   // mode1
}
else {
   // mode2
}
```